# Maui Query Parameter single string item will not work

Tags: c#, maui

type here

Hello everyone, I have read many of the past issues related to this issue. Nothing has worked so far. Probably something simple I am missing.... So I thought more eyes on the problem would help. Here's what I have:

Relationships page has this button clicked routine:

```
 public async void OnButton2Clicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
 {
     Routing.RegisterRoute("Relationships/RelationshipDetail", typeof(RelationshipDetail));
     
     if(Sign1 != null | Sign2 == null)
     {
         Sign2 = getsign(rotate);
     }
     signs = Sign1 + "|" + Sign2;
    
     await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"Relationships/RelationshipDetail?signs={signs}");
 }
```

Then I have the RelationshipDetails page:

```
[QueryProperty(nameof(aSigns),"signs")]
public partial class RelationshipDetail : ContentPage
{
    string asigns;
    public string aSigns
    {
        get => asigns;
        set
        {
            asigns = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

The route works, but the set method never gets invoked. I have not used other types of objects (dictionary or an object) as that seems pointless until I get some type of reaction from the details page. No model is involved here.

[Here is the debug session, first breakpoint not hit.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7wGz.png)

I have went through most of the related issues here and nothing has worked.  I have checked the Maui Xaminals sample code... that works fine... (looking at the cats / cats detail pages.  The code there works, and the route, call and query property are setup almost identical.  What's up with my code?

Comment: Try without the pipe symbol

Comment: I tried that took out the pipe and jammed the two fields together.  looks like "GeminiGemini" and unfortunately that didn't work.  Worthy of a try!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In trying to reproduce your issue, I didn't see anything really major, except that registering a route in a button handler seems like an unconventional approach. It seemed to work fine if I moved it to the MainPage ctor and (in this case) set the `BindingContext` of the `RelationshipDetail`.

[image: demo]

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Routing.RegisterRoute("Relationships/RelationshipDetail", typeof(RelationshipDetail));
    }
    private async void OnNavigateClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var signs = "Some Value";
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"Relationships/RelationshipDetail?signs={signs}");
    }
}
```

---

```
[QueryProperty(nameof(aSigns), "signs")]
public partial class RelationshipDetail : ContentPage
{
    public RelationshipDetail()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = this;
    }
    public string? aSigns
    {
        get => asigns;
        set
        {
            asigns = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    string? asigns;
}
```

---

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="QueryPropertyOfRoute.RelationshipDetail"
             Title="Relationship Details">
    <Grid>
        <Label 
            Text="{Binding aSigns}"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" 
            VerticalTextAlignment="Center" 
            HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" 
            BackgroundColor="Azure"
            HeightRequest="40"
            WidthRequest="200"/>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Not quite the answer, but you did put me on the path.  I have an "InitializeUI" call after the InitializeComponent call.  I took that out of the "RelationshipDetail" code and it is working.  I did this after moving the property constructor below as you had it.  :) thanks for your code... it nudged me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

Moved out the "InitializeUIAsync" code and the property is being populated as expected! IV nudged me in the right direction!

This worked for me:

[image showing the property is now getting set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9R1O.png)